# Ckan 2.10 how to redirect url from www.example.com to /dataset?

Tags: ckan

I would like to redirect user to /dataset by default how can I do that ??

I tried toolkit return it dint worked I have my old url redirect on ckan2.8 with iroutes but currently in 2.10 is deprecated so what's these best solution

thansk in advance

Comment: Have you tried this setting in the ckan.ini file ?

``` ckan.auth.route_after_login```

Default value: dashboard.datasets
Allows to customize the route that the user will get redirected to after a successful login.